# How can I write an equation with no spaces in R Markdown?

Tags: r-markdown

I would like to write the symbol pi followed by + 1 without any spaces before or after the + in an R Markdown document that is being rendered with `bookdown::bookdown_site`. When I write `$\pi+1$` it adds a space before and after the +. How can I tell it to not add spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything in-between dollar signs will be interpreted as TeX, so I think what you want is some negative spaces (`\!`):

`$\pi\!+\!1$`

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution and it renders the spacing a bit differently:

```
$\pi{{+}}1$
```

So, if anybody else is trying to align a column perfectly and the `\!` is not exactly right give the `{{` notation a try.